# How can I fix style problems with a google map's info window?

Tags: css, google-maps

By default, a Google Map infowindow has really nasty style, such that the inner content overlaps the close button when a scrollbar is present:

[image]

Google, by their infinite wisdom, don't do anything as nice as using classes on their elements, so that makes styling the info window very difficult. Does anyone know how I can fix this overlap problem?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to wait until google has created the content before you try and manipulate the CSS.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
    infoWindow.open(googleMap, this);
    setTimeout(reposition, 500);
});

function reposition() {
    $(SELECTOR FOR YOUR CONTENT DIV).parent().parent().css({ top: '24px'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your own `div` with id and class into the window and style it; if you want even more control, get its parent (through `document.getElementById("yourdiv").parent`) and manipulate its CSS through DOM (e.g. reset the `overflow` property).

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't help. Since that div gets inserted into a google element that has 'overflow: auto', the scrollbar remains in the same position, with the close button overlapping it.